# On Onchange Event In jQuery Plugins by XDSoft DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my coding for onchange event in jQuery plugins by XDSoft DateTime Picker

```
<input type="text" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" class="form-control" id="txtdatetime">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {        
     jQuery('#txtdatetime').datetimepicker({
     startDate: '+1971/05/01',
     format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
     onChangeDateTime: function () {
     alert('yup');
     }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the available callbacks from [the doc](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

```
onSelectDate: function () {},
onSelectTime: function () {},
onChangeMonth: function () {},
onChangeYear: function () {},
onChangeDateTime: function () {}, //the one you're after
onShow: function () {},
onClose: function () {},
onGenerate: function () {}
```

So, your code becomes:

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtdatetime').datetimepicker({
        startDate: '+1971/05/01',
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        onChangeDateTime: myfunction
    });
});

function myfunction() {
    alert("yup");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(function () {

        jQuery('#txtdatetime').datetimepicker({
            startDate: '+1971/05/01',
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            onChangeDateTime: function () {
               //fire what you want
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of what you did and why it works

Comment: @depperm ..it has a change event onChangeDateTime ..obviously it will fire while changing the date